# How to add "advertisements" in the UIScrollView like BBC News app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have created the news app which use the "UIScrollView + UIWebView" to let users to swipe  through different news. However, I would like to ask whether it's possible for me to add the advertisements like the BBC News app or not, which users will see the advertisements while scrolling horizontally.

[image]

[image]

I was trying to use addSubView while scrolling (scrollViewDidScroll) but it replaces the existing content.

I realize BBC News app do the things like this,

Users swipe through the news --> After swiping a few times --> show the ads (in position 5, for instance) --> users swipe from start to the end again --> the ads appear again, but this time could be in position 3).

But I just don't know how to make it work for my app. Any clue? thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see some code. Calling `addSubview` wi bring your sub view to the front and put it at 0,0 in the parent view. Are you positioning your ad correctly in the scrollView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already have a functionality, where You have stored news articles data in some array. Or You fetch data from database into some array.

Well - I think the easiest way would be just to add advert_data in this news array.

For example - You fetch from db in array:

```
NSArray *mArray = @[
    "news1",
    "news2",
    "news3",
    "news4",
    "news5",
    "news6"];
```

then You could simply - iterate it all through, and add advert data. For example

```
int counter = 0;


while (counter < [mArray count])
{
    int mTmp = 3+(arc4random() % 2);   // atleast 3, but up to 5?

    counter +=mTmp;

    [mArray insertObject:"advert" atIndex:counter];

    counter +=1;  //we added one object, so we need to adjust counter
}
```

Then simply - when You try to load corresponding data in webview, check if content is not "advert".  If it  is - load some random advert html from somewhere.

P.S.  I guess, Your data arrays will have NSManagedObjects, instead of strings. Then You can check if `[mArray objectAtIndex:i]`   (when You try to load it into webview)-  is NSManagedObject or a string value.

I hope You understand this idea.